# Docker Compose when to use image over build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment

Docker Compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), and its [example use case](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case) were great to figure out the various possibilities you have to split different working environments (development, production, etc.).

```
web:
  image: example/my_web_app:latest
  links:
    - db
    - cache

db:
  image: postgres:latest

cache:
  image: redis:latest
```

However, it wasn't very clear to me when to use images over build.

That's the only description available that goes with their only `image: example/my_web_app:latest` example:

> Another common use case is running adhoc or administrative tasks
>   against one or more services in a Compose app. This example
>   demonstrates running a database backup.

The rest of their example cases use `build: .`

I understand that working with images over building gives you better performance when turning a container up for the first time, since images are already prepared builds. However, I can foresee many issues in doing so:

- [development] Developers might to change Dockerfile configuration (and they'll need to test it somehow before pushing any changes).
- [development] Source code files will change (but I guess you can fix that easily by sharing volumes).
- [production] You might not always want to be at the `:latest` version (or do you?).
- [any] by using images (and the `:latest` tag), you don't have control over the file versions you are touching. But rather everytime you turn up `docker-compose up` it'll will update to the latest working version.

*Some of the previous points might not be completely true. Feel free to dismantle them.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typically you would want to use `build .` in the following scenarios:

- development
- automated testing

This is normally done when you are developing or testing and the code is not production ready. e.g. tests fail, code does not compile, code errors, ect.

Normally you would only create an image when it is ready to ship for deployment.  At that point you would create the image, version it up via its tag and push it to your personal DTR or Docker Hub.

When working with versions in docker compose you are not bound to `:latest`, you can specify any version you want to ensure the proper version is running in any given environment.  For example, in production you may want to create a compose file called `docker-production.yaml` that is configured like so:

```
web:
  image: "example/my_web_app:${TAG}"
  links:
    - db
    - cache
db:
  image: postgres:9.5.2
cache:
  image: redis:3.0.7
```

Where `${TAG}` is an environment variable that is substituted in at runtime, e.g. `docker-compose up -d -f docker-production.yaml`.  You can read more about variable substitution [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution).

The power of compose is that you can create build files with variable substitutes that are automatically launched by your build system, no longer limiting you to `:latest` or even a hardcoded version.

Note:

1. How teams run their build, ship, deploy varies greatly as they
   figure out what works best for them and their product so the above
   `build .` scenarios may not be accurate for all cases, but is
   accurate for how my company uses compose.
2. This assumes `build .` in a [docker-compose context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) and not a `docker
   build` context.

Comment: Variable substitution docs seems to have moved [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#variable-substitution)

Answer (score 12):

As @GHETTO.CHiLD said, it depends on your needs and your work flow. Actually we **don't perform manual builds**. I'm going to explain how we manage this and why. It fits perfectly in our flow, but could not be suitable in other scenarios.

- We don't build images manually. The CI does it ([GitLab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/) in our case)
- We have 2 types of images, *development/testing* and *production*.
- There is a `docker-compose.yml` for development that ease the management of the environment. They just run `docker-compose up` and it pulls the image from the registry and mounts it's directory inside the container.

  ```
  version: "2"

  services:
    web:
      build: 
        context: ../../
        dockerfile: dockerfiles/dev/Dockerfile
      image: registry.my.domain/my_image:dev
      volumes:
        - ../../:/opt/app
      working_dir: /opt/app
  ```
- If they made changes to the Dockerfile (for example, they need a new library), they can build the image in their machine (`docker-compose build`), but the image is not pushed against the registry.
- When they're happy, they push the new code (which includes the Dockerfile) and the CI builds the new `dev` image and run the tests.
- The CI builds the images in the same host every time, so it can take advantage of caching. If the Dockerfile has no changes, the build takes less than a second.
- When a new tag is created, the CI builds a production image with the `$TAG` as the image tag.
- For production, we use an [orchestrator](http://rancher.com/), not a Compose YAML. We don't want to store sensitive data that can be in the `docker-compose.yml` in the project repository. To upgrade, we just pull the new tag from the registry (we can do this automatically, but I'm not confident yet to deploy to production without human testing before :D).

Of course you can build images every time for development, but there are projects that can take a long time to build. For example, Python3 + pandas can take 25 minutes to build, so it's frustating if you have to switch between projects often. On the other hand, pull an image takes less than a minute.

We use this approach because GitLab give us the CI, the Registry and the runners to build images and run tests. You can do it without it, but you will need to integrate all components on your own. The flow isn't perfect, it has some drawbacks, but are minor in our scenario.

Comment: +1 because you pointed out very interesting details, like how you deal with images and `Dockerfile` changes at the same time

Comment: Agree. You brought up very good points. We actually use swarm, ansible and Jenkins and have a very complex setup that is all automated and rolls containers as they pass build tests. I tried to minimize scope on my reply because Docker and ci/cd can get very complicated very faster. Compose is great if you have a container that needs to be tested or if your requirements are small. Currently we manage over 300 containers in production and are build system is a little more complex then described above. @zurfyx pm if you want to chat privately.

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD I appreciate that from someone who's proficient with Docker, but I'm not sure how to contact you. Feel free to use any of the social platforms on my profile